# How do I select my active energy type for Energy powers?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, psionics

Several energy-based attack powers ([Energy Ray](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/psionics-unleashed/psionic-powers/e/energy-ray),[Energy Stun](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/psionics-unleashed/psionic-powers/e/energy-stun), etc.) use a particular energy type determined by your "active energy type".  However, I can't find any reference to how you are supposed to choose an active energy type.  The power descriptions say that "A kineticist does not need to select an energy type for this power when he gains psionic focus", which presumably means that the active energy type is chosen somehow when you gain psionic focus.

Is active energy type something that can be chosen freely whenever you gain psionic focus?  Is there a restriction to what energy type you pick?  Do you need to have psionic focus to manifest the power?  If you have psionic focus already, is there any way to change your active energy type without expending your focus first?  In general, how does picking an active energy type work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An excerpt from *Ultimate Psionics*, pg. 131 (Powers and Power Points), edited for clarity:

> Many psionic powers deal damage of a certain type of energy, with cold, electricity, fire, and sonic being the most common. For powers that have the choice of cold, electricity, fire, and sonic, the manifester must choose after he regains his psionic power points for the day (a full-round action performed after 8 hours of rest) which of these four energy types is his active energy.
>   The manifester may choose to change which energy is his active energy by gaining psionic focus. If he is currently maintaining psionic focus, he may expend it as a free action and then gain psionic focus normally to choose a new energy type. The manifester need not maintain psionic focus to have an active energy type.
>   Wilders may change their active energy type when performing a wild surge.
>   Kineticists are exempt from this restriction and may freely choose the energy type at the time the power is manifest, so long as it is within the choices allowed by the power. He could not, for example, choose fire as his energy type when manifesting *concussion blast*, as the power does not allow a choice in energy types.